# How to translate a standart module in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

Tried to translate the "newsletter"-module by creating the "uk_UA.csv" in the directory "app/code/Magento/Newsletter/i18n/uk_UA.csv", but this not working.

Do the same in the core of Magento, and it's working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe you just need to [clear some directories](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/howdoi/php/php_clear-dirs.html#howdoi-clear-what).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you know you shouldn't touch the vendor folder because it will be overwritten.

You can do it the following way (which I think it is best practice):

Create path:

```
/app/i18n/magento/uk_ua/
```

In that folder create 4 files:

composer.json

```
{
"name": "magento/uk_ua",
  "description": "Ukrainian",
  "version": "100.0.1",
  "license": [
    "OSL-3.0",
    "AFL-3.0"
  ],
  "require": {
    "magento/framework": "100.0.*"
  },
  "type": "magento2-language",
  "autoload": {
    "files": [
      "registration.php"
    ]
  }
}
```

uk_UA.csv

```
"some newsletter text","changed newsletter text"
```

language.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<language xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/Language/package.xsd">
    <code>uk_UA</code>
    <vendor>magento</vendor>
    <package>uk_ua</package>
</language>
```

registration.php

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::LANGUAGE,
    'magento_uk_ua',
    __DIR__
);

?>
```

Bare in mind that it is case sensitive. Path, registration and vendor are `uk_ua`, but csv and code is `uk_UA`.