# How to translate core Magento modules and create a CSV translation file per module?

Tags: magento2, module, localisation

I want to translate all core modules in Magento 2 without touching the vendor folder and without translating all modules in one CSV file as suggested in [this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/120406/how-to-translate-a-standart-module-in-magento-2)

I want to  translate each single module in one related CSV file, like:

```
app/code/magento/<modulename>/i18n/lg_LG.csv
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems like for **language packs** you cannot create separate CSV files per module anymore (which makes sense given that translations are not scoped by module anymore, see: [How does translation scope work in Magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/104732/how-does-translation-scope-work-in-magento-2))

#### From the [documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/translations/xlate.html#m2devgde-xlate-languagepack):

> - Language packages that contain a entire dictionary in one directory.
>
>   You can distribute this language package as a standalone component
>     (similar to modules and themes). **Interestingly, it violates Magento’s
>     modularity principles on purpose;** that is, so that a system integrator
>     can translations variations provided by extensions.

*(highlight added)*

Since language packs are the only way to provide core translations for a composer based installation, I don't see any way to do it differently.